# Visual Studio 2017 Installation of "ASP.NET and web development"

Tags: asp.net, web, visual-studio-2017

I've downloaded Visual Studio with `--layout` option, and installed it.

Installation was successful with warning, as below,

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Mobile development with JavaScript (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Node.js development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node,version=15.0.26208.0)

Incomplete components
    .NET Core 1.0 - 1.1 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.0.26208.0)
    .NET Core 1.0.1 development tools (Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Container development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Git for Windows (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Git,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Visual Studio Emulator for Android (Component.Android.Emulator,version=15.0.26208.0)
```

There errors were listed in log file.

Every time I modify the Installer and try to install web components, doesn't work.
I've tried to restart computer, restart the installer.
Nothing works.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/talk-to-us Microsoft is listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging,
I found a solution.

Try to install Visual Studio with setting `temp` and `%temp%` folder to short path, like `d:\temp`.

Step 1 : open `cmd` with administrator privileges (to ignore administrative privileges error).

Step 2 : execute command - `set tmp="d:\temp"`

Step 3 : execute command - `set temp="d:\temp"`

Step 4 : execute `vs_community.exe` with whatever `--layout` option you want.